# Inserting R data frame using RMySQL, dbWriteTable fails with unknown column row_names

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Trying to insert a data frame into a MySQL using the following code.

The data frame:
q <- data.frame( ... )

```
      import_id     time     xpos     ypos     zpos     gaps      xvel          yvel       zvel trajectory runs
22651         2 188.7500 0.198364 0.484194 0.121778 0.000000 0.0000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000          0    1
22652         2 188.7583 0.200871 0.484247 0.119759 0.008333 0.3008520  0.0063602544 -0.2422897          1    6
22653         2 188.7667 0.203763 0.484246 0.117860 0.008334 0.3470122 -0.0001199904 -0.2278618          1    6
22654         2 188.7750 0.206539 0.484070 0.115836 0.008333 0.3331333 -0.0211208448 -0.2428897          1    6
22655         2 188.7833 0.209603 0.483557 0.113943 0.008333 0.3676947 -0.0615624625 -0.2271691          1    6
22656         2 188.7917 0.212570 0.482920 0.111810 0.008334 0.3560115 -0.0764338853 -0.2559395          1    6
```

RMySQL code:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = mysql_conn, name = "master", value = q, 
                          append = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, row.names = TRUE, 
                          field.types = list(import_id="int(11)", time="float(15,8)", 
                                           xpos = "float(15,8)", ypos = "float(15,8)", zpos = "float(15,8)",
                                           gpas = "float(15,8)", xvel = "float(15,8)", yvel = "float(15,8)",
                                           zvel = "float(15,8)", trajectory = "int(11)", runs = "int(11)"))
```

Error:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement:
>   Unknown column 'row_names' in 'field list'

Comment: Isn't the error straightforward? R's `row.names(df)` is attempting to migrate into a MySQL table that does not have a column named `row_names`?

Comment: But where does row_names come from? It’s not in the data frame

Comment: Have you tried writing this to a different table in the db just to see if it works? Also, have you tried reading the table you can't currently write to into R, grabbing the column names, and ensuring they match the column names of the data you're trying to append?

Comment: Every data frame in R has a `row.names` property. Because you selected `row.names = TRUE`, RMySQL maps the df's `row.names` to a column named `row_names`. Try setting this argument to `FALSE`.

Comment: @Parfait thanks that resolved the issue. The MySQL table must have row_names column if we are to set row.names = T